# How do I use submodules in GitHub Actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I am trying to create a **CI github action**, and I have problems **accessing a file** that is in a **submodule** of the repository:

```
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'directory_in_sub_module/requirements.txt'
```

Now my question is how do I access files located in **submodules** through **github actions**?

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed, the linked question indeed has the same title, but the question is specifically for working with private repositories, and using the accepted solution as a solution to this question is overkill as it would use secrets or a token.

Answer (score 4):

I just needed to **checkout** all the submodules by just running:

```
- name: checkout all the submodules
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
  with:
    submodules: recursive
```

Comment: This works for public submodules. Private ones, with ssh, it may require more trickery.

Comment: recursive vs true. Do you know the difference?

Comment: To understand how the checkout action works, go to their official example: https://github.com/actions/checkout. If we recursively clone submodules, we would be cloning submodules along with submodules of submodules. This is not always what you want, as you may just want submodules included in the base repo and no others, in that case we just want use submodules so set `submodules: true`